# Finding dependency from multiple arrays

Tags: javascript

I want to find all the dependent of a particular item from an object.

```
{
   "x": ["a", "b"],
   "a": ["1", "2"],
   "b": [],
   "1": ["abc"],
   "2": [],
   "abc": []
}
```

Desired output: all the dependencies of items

```
{
   "x" : ["a", "b", "1", "2", "abc"],
   "a" : ["1", "2", "abc"],
   "1" : ["abc"]
}
```

Comment: are `a`, `b`, and `abc` variables?

Comment: nope.. they are just file names

Comment: Looks like you would need to go through your object and recursively read out the values for each key

Comment: Without the quotes in the array, it won't work... Now the parser will look for variables like `a` and `b` (which I imagine you have not defined separately).

Comment: hmm.. yes. Do you have any samples/ links?

Comment: @nils - the code is just an example. My object actually is a big object with file names.

Comment: You're computing the transitive closure of a directed graph.   Output should also include b = [], 3 = [], and abc = [] if it's to be the proper full transitive closure.

Comment: I added all the needed quotes but now they're gone... I'm NOT going to fix t again

Comment: @6502 Because your edit changed the question, the value of `a` and the string `"a"` are not the same thing.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: _"[nope.. they are just file names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494572/finding-dependency-from-multiple-arrays#comment52849013_32494572)"_ The OP forgot the quotes when writing a quick example of what he wants to do. He _explicitly_ commented that those aren't variables.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek it seems as though the intention was that `a` is a string that references the property `a` on the Object as opposed to a variable `a`...

Comment: If the answer works for you, please don't forget to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically need two functions:

1. One to loop through your object and find the properties: `loopObject`
2. One to resolve your dependencies: `getDependencies`

For every property in `loopObject`, `getDependencies` is called on every item in the array of the property recursively.

In the end, `loopObject` returns the new object with all the dependencies.

```js
var searchDependencies = {
  "x": ["a", "b"],
  "a": ["1", "2"],
  "b": [],
  "1": ["abc"],
  "2": [],
  "abc": []
};

function loopObject(obj) {
  var resObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(item) {
    resObj[item] = getDependencies(obj[item], obj);
    if(resObj[item].length < 1) {
        delete resObj[item];
    }
  });

  return resObj;
}

function getDependencies(arr, obj){
  var resArr = arr;
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    resArr = resArr.concat(getDependencies(obj[item], obj));
  });
  return resArr;
}

var resolvedDependencies = loopObject(searchDependencies);

console.log(resolvedDependencies);
```

Check out the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrzutjwa/1/) for a working example.

**A word of caution**

Watch out that you don't have cyclical dependecies, eg.:

```
 {
    "a": ["b"],
    "b": ["a"]
 }
```

Otherwise you will be stuck in an endless loop.

Comment: The solution is inaccurate - "b", "2" & "abc" are not supposed to be in the output.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tested this, but it should be close to what you need to do:

```
function getDeps(name){
  var deps = arr[name];
  deps.forEach(function(name){
    deps = deps.concat(getDeps(name));
  });
  return deps;
}
```

You need to search recursively through the array for each filename.